# Mongodb find subset in array field from input array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Suppose I have db as below,

```
const data = [
  {
    "chapter": 1,
    "targets": [
      {
        type: 'user',
        recipientId: 1
      }
    ],
    "challenge": [
      {
        "activate": true,
        "challengeId": "ch-1"
      },
      {
        "activate": true,
        "challengeId": "ch-2"
      },
      {
        "activate": true,
        "challengeId": "ch-3"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "chapter": 1,
    "targets": [
      {
        type: 'user',
        recipientId: 2
      }
    ],
    "challenge": [
      {
        "activate": true,
        "challengeId": "ch-2"
      },
      {
        "activate": true,
        "challengeId": "ch-3"
      },
      {
        "activate": true,
        "challengeId": "ch-4"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "chapter": 1,
    "targets": [
      {
        type: 'user',
        recipientId: 3
      }
    ],
    "challenge": [
      {
        "activate": true,
        "challengeId": "ch-4"
      },
      {
        "activate": true,
        "challengeId": "ch-5"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "chapter": 1,
    "targets": [
      {
        type: 'user',
        recipientId: 4
      }
    ],
    "challenge": [
      {
        "activate": true,
        "challengeId": "ch-2"
      },
      {
        "activate": false,
        "challengeId": "ch-3"
      },
      {
        "activate": true,
        "challengeId": "ch-4"
      },
    ]
  },
],
```

and I want to query using an array of `recipientId` if I input
`[1,2]` it should turn the intersect of `challengeId` the expected output is

```
[
{"challengeId": "ch-2"},
{"challengeId": "ch-3"}
]
```

if the input is `[1,2,3]` it should return `[]` because there is no intersection with this input

and if the input is `[1,2,4]` also return

```
[
{"challengeId": "ch-2"},
]
```

because `challengeId ch-3` of `recipientId 4` does not activate yet.

I have been reading `$setIntersection` but it seems does not solve my issue.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can go quite close to your result using this query. You might just want clean up the result.

```
const input = [1,2,4]
db.test.aggregate([
  //filter by input array
  { $match: { "targets.recipientId": { $in: input } } },
  // Unwind the challenge array
  { $unwind: "$challenge" },
  //filter out the non-active ones
  { $match: { "challenge.activate": true } },
  //group by challengeId and keep track of the count
  { $group: { _id: "$challenge.challengeId", count: { $sum: 1 } } },
  //filter out the challengeId with count < input.length
  { $match: { count: { $gte: input.length } } },
]);

result: {"_id":"ch-2","count":3}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, it seems correct as I expect. Need to test many cases for this one. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some custom logic, because `$setIntersecion` is not able to accept dynamic array field,

- `$match` to `recipientId` field
- `$project` to filter challenges is `activate: ture`
- `$group` by null to count total documents
- `$unwind` challenges array 2 time because we have grouped it in above for count purpose
- `$group` by `challengeId` and get count of challenges
- `$match` to check total document count and challenge count are same
- `$project` to show required fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "targets.recipientId": { $in: [1, 2, 4] } } },
  {
    $project: {
      challenge: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$challenge",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.activate", true] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      challenge: { $push: "$challenge" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$challenge" },
  { $unwind: "$challenge" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$challenge.challengeId",
      cCount: { $sum: 1 },
      count: { $first: "$count" }
    }
  },
  { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$count", "$cCount"] } } },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      challengeId: "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hhnzsZMPGVZ)